# Can I display the conflicting primary key when I get the error: The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am having an issue deleting a row in SQL Server 2008 because of a primary key constraint:

> *The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint...*

Is there any way I can have the conflicting primary key displayed in the error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing built into SQL server (or competing products) that will tell you which specific table and row is causing the conflict.  The error message only tells which FK to inspect.

Based on [the answer that JLo gave](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14959754), you could make your own [on before delete] trigger for your table(s) that will walk down each FK table and count related records.  If you are using SPs, you could use a try/catch block to do the same thing.

You have my sympathy because something like that would be pretty tedious to write.  If you were doing this for more than a few tables, I would recommend using a code generator (T4 toolkit or MyGeneration) to generate those for you.

Answer (score 1):

This will give you the foreign keys for a specific table. You'll have to check each of the pairings yourself.

```
SELECT
    f.name as [Foreign Key],
    OBJECT_NAME(f.parent_object_id) as [Table],
    COL_NAME(fc.parent_object_id, fc.parent_column_id) as [Column],
    OBJECT_NAME(f.referenced_object_id) as [Reference Table],
    COL_NAME(fc.referenced_object_id, fc.referenced_column_id) as [Reference Column]
FROM sys.foreign_keys f
JOIN sys.foreign_key_columns fc
    ON fc.constraint_object_id = f.object_id
WHERE fc.parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[Document]')
```

That should get you started... good luck!

Comment: Thanks. I already have the relationship though - it's included in the error message. This query still is useful for displaying the relationships.

Comment: If it's already displayed in the error message, why are you asking how to display it? I may have missed the point of the question

Comment: I'm looking for the primary key of the row that's in conflict to be displayed. For example - the Id 123 in TableA is being referenced by TableB.

Answer (score 0):

The value that it's getting constrained on is one of the values you are trying to delete, so ex.

```
delete from tableA where value = 123
```

Would throw a constraint error if there was a foreign key constraint somewhere in another table with the value of 123... this is why naming your constraints properly is important, but if not, you can always run J LO's script to figure out which constraints are available.

On something more complex like

```
delete from tableA where value IN (select top 10 * from tableA)
```

Change your delete into a select * from and cross reference those values using an IN statement similar to the above... you can also run my subquery directly, but it's just an example.